# How to build some packet in tensorflow with debug mode\

Tags: debugging, tensorflow, bazel

I encountered the problem that I wanted to have a debug, then I wanted to build a debug version of tensorflow, using the following command:
bazel build --compilation_mode=dbg -s //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package

but it will trigger the longtime link in protobuf for almost oneday, and still not finished.

and my intension is to build some other package which is used by tensorflow with debug mode, could I configure the bazel build file to get some debug package separately?

Comment: PLEASE: read the following link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and correct the title and improve the text of the question. 
Try to make it understandable and provide enough context that others may need to help you resolve the problem. @maricoxu

Comment: One-day long build sounds abnormal. A clean build of TF on a Macbook takes a couple hours maximum. What machine are you using (desktop? Raspberry PI?), how much RAM does it have, what operating system does it run, is Bazel printing anything interesting?

Comment: thanks for the help, and I used ubuntu 16.04 on the desktop I7 with the 16GB RAM. I'm ok with the normal build, but it always exist the problem with the debug mode

Answer (score 0):

To understand the issue better, try running the neverending action manually:

1. start the debug build, wait for it to get stuck in the protobuf linking action
2. interrupt the build (Ctrl+C)
3. run the build again with the `-s` flag, so Bazel shows the command line it executes (you could've ran step 1. with the `-s` flag, but then there's a lot more output and it's harder to find the right information)
4. interrupt the build again
5. `cd` into the directory shown in the by command and set environment variables
6. try running the command that failed (you may need to change the output paths because they are sometimes not user-writable) and see if it still never finishes

What you just did is running the same command Bazel was running and getting stuck on. If the command is stuck in this manual mode too, then the error might be with the linker (I doubt this is the case though). But if it succeeds, then the problem is with Bazel.